# bootstrap 3.0: align li to bottom of parent div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I'm working on a site built on Bootstrap 3, which obviously is responsive. I have a three column setup in the header, where the logo goes on the left, the main menu in the middle and social media links in the right column. The width of the logo is set top 25% to match columns further down the page, which means that it will change size depending on screen size. Using the `margin-top: X px` to match the height of this image, will thusly not work in two out of three views. I've been through using `display: inline-block` / `vertical-align: bottom`, on various elements, starting from `.navbar-default`, and through variations down to `.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a`. Nothing works here.

If someone could point me in the right direction on this one, I'll much appreciate it.

This is the css that I'm currently using, minus failed attempts at various vertical-aligns:

```
.navbar-default {background: none;border-radius: 0px;border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid @bordercolor;padding-top: 45px; 
    .navbar-nav {padding-left: 15px;
        li {background: none;display: inline-block;vertical-align: bottom;
            a {padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; border: 1px solid fade(@links, 40%);vertical-align: bottom; }
        }
        .active>a, {background: darken(@body, 5%);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the design is, but you should use a browser's developer tools and manipulate the CSS to figure out exactly what properties to override as bootstrap is very picky about this.

Comment: Believe me, I've tried that. Something quirky is going on, and I'm not sure what it is. Using line-height to match the image works until resize. The same applies to all the other solutions I've googled my way into. Static size on the logo, yes. Responsive size, no.